# Probability Problem: Drawing balls from an urn.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem is stated as such:

"An urn contains $n$ red and $m$ blue balls. They are withdrawn one at a time until a total of $r$, $r \leq n$, red balls have been withdrawn. Find the probability that a total of $k$ balls are withdrawn. *Hint*: A total of $k$ balls will be withdrawn if there are $r − 1$ red balls in the ﬁrst $k − 1$ withdrawals and the $k$th withdrawal is a red ball."

The answer that I have come up with is
$$\frac{{n \choose r-1}{m \choose k-r}(n-r+1)}{{n+m \choose k-1}(n+m-k+1)}$$
which I am fairly confident in.

Several of the solutions I have found have claimed the solution to be
$$\frac{{n \choose r-1}{m \choose n-r}(n-r+1)}{{n+m \choose k-1}(n+m-k+1)}.$$
If these are indeed also correct, then I don't see where $m \choose n-r$ could be coming from. Would this not imply that $n=k$?

Comment: why denominator is not $\binom{n+m}{k}$

Comment: This is because of what is indicated by the hint. We are splitting the experiment up into two parts, drawing the first $k - 1$ balls, then drawing the $k$th ball. We are multiplying the probability of the first $k-1$ balls being red by the conditional probability of the $k$th ball being red.

Comment: Ya got it and your answer is correct may be the second answer has a typo

Comment: I assumed that to be the case, but I found multiple solutions online making that claim. It's possible that all of them just blindly copied from an erroneous original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A numerical example shows that the second expression cannot be right. Take $n=m=2$ and $r=1$; clearly $k$ can only be $1,2$, or $3$. Then

$$\frac{\binom{n}{r-1}\binom{m}{n-r}(n-r+1)}{\binom{n+m}{k-1}(n+m-k+1)}=\frac4{\binom4{k-1}(5-k)}\;,$$

and

$$\sum_{k=1}^3\frac4{\binom4{k-1}(5-k)}=\frac44+\frac4{12}+\frac4{12}=\frac53\;,$$

which is nonsense: the sum has to be $1$.

Your expression is correct, and we may note as a small check that it passes this test:

$$\frac{\binom{n}{r-1}\binom{m}{k-r}(n-r+1)}{\binom{n+m}{k-1}(n+m-k+1)}=\frac{2\binom2{k-1}}{\binom4{k-1}(5-k)}\;,$$

so

$$\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{2\binom2{k-1}}{\binom4{k-1}(5-k)}=\frac24+\frac4{12}+\frac2{12}=1\;.$$

Comment: I assumed it to be an error. My guess is that the multiple places I saw the incorrect expression were from a common source. Much appreciated! I should have thought to verify it in some simple cases.

Comment: @Brian: That would be my guess as well. You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer, of course, is correct,

but ignoring the $r_{th}$ red ball for counting favorable ways, we get a shorter formula. (I have replaced $n$ and $m$ by $R$ and $B$ for greater symbolic clarity)

$$\frac{{k-1\choose r-1}{R+B-k\choose R-r}}{R+B\choose R}$$